# Create BED file from list with gene symbols

Tags: fasta, genome, bed

Is there a way to generate a BED file of a list of gene symbols for a given genome?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Via Gencode and BEDOPS `convert2bed`:

```
$ wget -qO- ftp://ftp.ebi.ac.uk/pub/databases/gencode/Gencode_human/release_28/gencode.v28.annotation.gff3.gz \
    | gunzip --stdout - \
    | awk '$3 == "gene"' - \
    | convert2bed -i gff - \
    > genes.bed
```

Replace the FTP path with that needed for your genome of interest. Feel free to edit your question if you need help with that, by specifying your given genome.

You can modify the `awk` statement to get exons, by replacing `gene` with `exon`.

BEDOPS: https://github.com/bedops/bedops

Once you have the genes in BED format, you can `grep` the file for them, using a text file of matches:

```
$ grep -Fwf genes_of_interest.txt genes.bed > genes_of_interest.bed
```

Answer (score 3):

You could also get your genes from [UCSC](https://genome-euro.ucsc.edu/cgi-bin/hgTables). Here's how:

[image]